# How to separate fields in a column (into their own named columns) and then remove repeated words from each entry

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a tsv file with 9 variables, as follows:

```
> seqnames  start   endwidth    strand  metadata    X.10logMacsq    annotation  distanceToTSS
```

The metadata column contains information I want to do some analysis on, but I first need to split the entries and put them into their own columns (with a heading).
The metadata looks like this (1st row):

```
ID=SRX067411;Name=H3K27ac%20(@%20HMEC);Title=GSM733660:%20Bernstein%20HMEC%20H3K27ac;Cell%20group=Breast;<br>source_name=HMEC;biomaterial_provider=Lonza;lab=Broad;lab%20description=Bernstein%20-%20Broad%20Institute;datatype=ChipSeq;datatype%20description=Chromatin%20IP%20Sequencing;cell%20organism=human;cell%20description=mammary%20epithelial%20cells;cell%20karyotype=normal;cell%20lineage=ectoderm;cell%20sex=U;antibody%20antibodydescription=rabbit%20polyclonal.%20Antibody%20Target:%20H3K27ac;
```

There are 27 entries for this column (per row) in total (not all shown here) but I thought I'd write them all into their own columns first, and then remove the ones I don't need afterwards. Once they have a descriptive column heading, then I could also remove their names (e.g.: ID=SRX would simply be SRX and so forth)

Sample file input (1st row)

```
seqnames    start   end width   strand  metadata    X.10logMacsq    annotation  geneChr geneStart   geneEnd geneLength  geneStrand  geneId  distanceToTSS
chr2    1711333 1711568 236 *   ID=SRX067411;Name=H3K27ac%20(@%20HMEC);Title=GSM733660:%20Bernstein%20HMEC%20H3K27ac;Cell%20group=Breast;<br>source_name=HMEC;biomaterial_provider=Lonza;lab=Broad;lab%20description=Bernstein%20-%20Broad%20Institute;datatype=ChipSeq;datatype%20description=Chromatin%20IP%20Sequencing; 447 Intron (uc002qxa.3/7837, intron 1 of 22)    1   1635659 1748291 112633  2   7837    36723
```

Can anyone help me out with this or give some advice? I am fairly new to Bash and not very comfortable with the commands yet.

So far I've just managed to clean the file up a bit with:

```
cut --complement -f 9-14 hisHMECanno.tsv | sed 's/%20/ /g' > hisHMECannoFilt.tsv
```

(the orginal files had some unneccessary columns that I just removed as well)

Then I have been trying to use awk to separate the entries into tab separated columns, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following perl script uses the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module to read the TSV file and to output properly formatted TSV data.

It automatically quotes fields if required and uses `Text::CSV`'s `undef_str` setting to output undefined metadata fields as a quoted empty string `""` (with commented out examples of how to print them as `N/A` or `--` instead).

At most, only one of those 3 lines should be uncommented, the others should be deleted or commented out. If you just want those fields to be empty, delete/comment out all three of those lines.

I recommend having something in those undefined fields because it will make it easier to post-process the output of this script with other tools that might treat two or more tabs (i.e. an empty field) the same as just a single tab (e.g. both `awk` and `perl` will do that by default, unless you tell them not to by explicitly setting the field separator to a single tab, rather than the default of "any amount of whitespace").

`Text::CSV` is packaged for debian and related distros as `libtext-csv-perl` (pure perl version) and `libtext-csv-xs-perl` (faster compiled C module).  Install both with `apt install libtext-csv-perl`.  Other distros probably have it packaged too.  Otherwise, install it with `cpan`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV qw(csv);

my $csv=Text::CSV->new({sep_char => "\t", quote_space => 0});

# optional: define how to print undefined fields
#$csv->undef_str ('--');
#$csv->undef_str ('N/A');
$csv->undef_str ('""');

# get header line, split into an arrayref called $cols
my $cols = $csv->getline(*ARGV);

# get first data row, extract headers & data from metadata field
my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV);

# The following line assumes that the metadata in the FIRST data row
# contains ALL of the metadata fields in the exact order you want them
# included in the output.
#
my $md_headers = extract_metadata_headers($$row[4]);
#
# If this is not the case, then delete the extract_metadata_headers
# subroutine and define the metadata fields manually with something
# like:
#
#my $md_headers = [
#  'ID', 'Name', 'Title', 'Cell group', 'source_name',
#  'biomaterial_provider', 'lab', 'lab description', 'datatype',
#  'datatype description', 'cell organism', 'cell description',
#  'cell karyotype', 'cell lineage', 'cell sex',
#  'antibody antibodydescription'
#];
# This defines both the extra metadata headers **and** the order
# that they will be included in each output row.

# extract the data from the metadata field
my $md_data = extract_metadata($$row[4]);

# replace the metadata header in $cols aref with the md headers
splice @$cols,4,1,@$md_headers;

# replace the metadata field in $row aref with the md fields
splice @$row,4,1,@$md_data;

# print the updated header line and the first row of data
$csv->say(*STDOUT,$cols);
$csv->say(*STDOUT,$row);

# main loop: extract and print the rest of the data
while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
  my $md_data = extract_metadata($$row[4]);
  splice @$row,4,1,@$md_data;

  $csv->say(*STDOUT,$row);
}

###
### subroutines
###

sub extract_metadata_headers {
  my $md = clean_metadata(shift);
  my @metadata = split /;/, $md;
  my @headers=();

  foreach (@metadata) {
    next if m/^\s*$/; # skip empty metadata
    my ($key,$val) = split /=/;
    push @headers, $key;
  };

  return \@headers;
};

sub extract_metadata {
  my $md = clean_metadata(shift);
  my @metadata = split /;/, $md;
  my %data=();

  foreach (@metadata) {
    next if m/^\s*$/; # skip empty metadata
    my ($key,$val) = split /=/;
    $data{$key} = $val;
  };

  return [@data{@$md_headers}];
};

sub clean_metadata {
    my $md = shift;
    $md =~ s/%(\d\d)/chr hex $1/eg; # decode %-encoded spaces etc.
    $md =~ s/<[^>]*>//g;            # remove HTML crap like <br>
    return $md;
};
```

Save it as, e.g., `process-tsv.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x process-tsv.pl` and give it a filename argument when you run it.  e.g.

```
$ ./process-tsv.pl filename.tsv
```

It will produce output like this to stdout:

```
$ ./process-tsv.pl input.tsv
seqnames        start   endwidth        strand  ID      Name    Title   Cell group      source_name     biomaterial_provider    lab     lab description datatype        datatype description    cell organism   cell description      cell karyotype   cell lineage    cell sex        antibody antibodydescription    X.10logMacsq    annotation      distanceToTSS
seq1    1       10      X       SRX067411       H3K27ac (@ HMEC)        GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac       Breast  HMEC    Lonza   Broad   Bernstein - Broad Institute     ChipSeq Chromatin IP Sequencing human   mammary epithelial cells       normal  ectoderm        U       rabbit polyclonal. Antibody Target: H3K27ac     x10     annot   dist
seq2    2       20      Y       SRX067411       H3K27ac (@ HMEC)        GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac       ""      ""      Lonza   Broad   Bernstein - Broad Institute     ChipSeq Chromatin IP Sequencing human   mammary epithelial cells       normal  ectoderm        U       ""      Y10     annot2  dist2
```

You can, of course, redirect the output to a file in your shell:

```
./process-tsv.pl input.tsv > output.tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, this might be what you're trying to do but without sample input/output we can test with it's a guess:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    gsub(/%20/," ")
    gsub(/<br>/,"")
}
NR==1 {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
NR==2 {
    orig = $0
    gsub(/=[^=;]+;/,OFS,$6)
    sub(OFS"$","",$6)
    tags = $6
    $0 = hdr
    $6 = tags
    print
    $0 = orig
}
{
    gsub(/[^=;]+=/,OFS,$6)
    sub("^"OFS,"",$6)
    gsub(/;/,"",$6)
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
>       seqnames        start   endwidth        strand  ID      Name    Title   Cell group      source_name     biomaterial_provider    lab     lab description datatype        datatype description    cell organism   cell description        cell karyotype  cell lineage    cell sex        antibody antibodydescription    X.10logMacsq    annotation      distanceToTSS
>       foo     bar     etc     anon    SRX067411       H3K27ac (@ HMEC)        GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac       Breast  HMEC    Lonza   Broad  Bernstein - Broad Institute      ChipSeq Chromatin IP Sequencing human   mammary epithelial cells        normal  ectoderm        U       rabbit polyclonal. Antibody Target: H3K27ac     end     more    stuff
```

The above was run using this input file:

```
$ cat file
>       seqnames        start   endwidth        strand  metadata        X.10logMacsq    annotation      distanceToTSS
>       foo     bar     etc     anon    ID=SRX067411;Name=H3K27ac%20(@%20HMEC);Title=GSM733660:%20Bernstein%20HMEC%20H3K27ac;Cell%20group=Breast;<br>source_name=HMEC;biomaterial_provider=Lonza;lab=Broad;lab%20description=Bernstein%20-%20Broad%20Institute;datatype=ChipSeq;datatype%20description=Chromatin%20IP%20Sequencing;cell%20organism=human;cell%20description=mammary%20epithelial%20cells;cell%20karyotype=normal;cell%20lineage=ectoderm;cell%20sex=U;antibody%20antibodydescription=rabbit%20polyclonal.%20Antibody%20Target:%20H3K27ac;       end     more    stuff
```

where all spaces are tabs.

You can see how the values line up with the tags (column header strings) by using `column` to make it visually tabular:

Input:

```
$ column -s$'\t' -t file
>  seqnames  start  endwidth  strand  metadata                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           X.10logMacsq  annotation  distanceToTSS
>  foo       bar    etc       anon    ID=SRX067411;Name=H3K27ac%20(@%20HMEC);Title=GSM733660:%20Bernstein%20HMEC%20H3K27ac;Cell%20group=Breast;<br>source_name=HMEC;biomaterial_provider=Lonza;lab=Broad;lab%20description=Bernstein%20-%20Broad%20Institute;datatype=ChipSeq;datatype%20description=Chromatin%20IP%20Sequencing;cell%20organism=human;cell%20description=mammary%20epithelial%20cells;cell%20karyotype=normal;cell%20lineage=ectoderm;cell%20sex=U;antibody%20antibodydescription=rabbit%20polyclonal.%20Antibody%20Target:%20H3K27ac;  end           more        stuff
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
>  seqnames  start  endwidth  strand  ID         Name              Title                              Cell group  source_name  biomaterial_provider  lab    lab description              datatype  datatype description     cell organism  cell description          cell karyotype  cell lineage  cell sex  antibody antibodydescription                 X.10logMacsq  annotation  distanceToTSS
>  foo       bar    etc       anon    SRX067411  H3K27ac (@ HMEC)  GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac  Breast      HMEC         Lonza                 Broad  Bernstein - Broad Institute  ChipSeq   Chromatin IP Sequencing  human          mammary epithelial cells  normal          ectoderm      U         rabbit polyclonal. Antibody Target: H3K27ac  end           more        stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
$ mlr --tsv put -S '
    $metadata = gsub($metadata,"%20"," "); $metadata = gsub($metadata,"<br>|;$","")
  ' then put -S '
  $* = mapsum($*,splitkvx($metadata,"=",";"))
' then cut -x -f metadata HisHMECanno.tsv
seqnames        start   end     width   strand  X.10logMacsq    annotation      geneChr geneStart       geneEnd geneLength                                                 geneStrand       geneId  distanceToTSS   ID      Name    Title   Cell group      source_name     biomaterial_provider   lab                                                 lab description  datatype        datatype description
chr2    1711333 1711568 236     *       447     Intron (uc002qxa.3/7837, intron 1 of 22)        1       1635659 1748291                                                    112633   2       7837    36723   SRX067411       H3K27ac (@ HMEC)        GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac       Breast HMEC                                                Lonza    Broad   Bernstein - Broad Institute     ChipSeq Chromatin IP Sequencing
```

The two `put` commands could be combined, however I think it's clearer to separate them into a "data cleanup" step and a "field splitting" step.

Changing the output format to CSV to make the field splits clearer:

```
mlr --itsv --ocsv put -S '
  $metadata = gsub($metadata,"%20"," "); $metadata = gsub($metadata,"<br>|;$","")
' then put -S '
  $* = mapsum($*,splitkvx($metadata,"=",";"))
' then cut -x -f metadata HisHMECanno.tsv
seqnames,start,end,width,strand,X.10logMacsq,annotation,geneChr,geneStart,geneEnd,geneLength,geneStrand,geneId,distanceToTSS,ID,Name,Title,Cell group,source_name,biomaterial_provider,lab,lab description,datatype,datatype description
chr2,1711333,1711568,236,*,447,"Intron (uc002qxa.3/7837, intron 1 of 22)",1,1635659,1748291,112633,2,7837,36723,SRX067411,H3K27ac (@ HMEC),GSM733660: Bernstein HMEC H3K27ac,Breast,HMEC,Lonza,Broad,Bernstein - Broad Institute,ChipSeq,Chromatin IP Sequencing
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Python dictionary and list data structures., in conjunction with regexes and list comprehension.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, re
ifile = sys.argv[1]
fs,rs = ofs,ors = "\t","\n"
with open(ifile) as f:
  for nr,l in enumerate(f,1):
    F = l.rstrip(rs).split(fs)
    if nr == 1:
      H = F
      idx_md = F.index("metadata")
      continue
    md_hdrs = re.findall(r"[^=;]+(?==)",F[idx_md])
    md = dict(t.split("=") for t in re.sub(r";+$","",F[idx_md]).split(";"))
    if nr == 2:
      print(*H[:idx_md], *md_hdrs, *H[idx_md+1:], sep=ofs)
    print(*F[:idx_md], *[md.get(key,"") for key in md_hdrs], *F[idx_md+1:], sep=ofs)
' file
```

Output:

```
seqnames    start   end width   strand  ID  Name    Title   Cell%20group    <br>source_name biomaterial_provider    lab lab%20description   datatype    datatype%20description  X.10logMacsq    annotation  geneChr geneStart   geneEnd geneLength  geneStrand  geneId  distanceToTSS
chr2    1711333 1711568 236 *   SRX067411   H3K27ac%20(@%20HMEC)    GSM733660:%20Bernstein%20HMEC%20H3K27ac Breast  HMEC    Lonza   Broad   Bernstein%20-%20Broad%20Institute   ChipSeq Chromatin%20IP%20Sequencing 447 Intron (uc002qxa.3/7837, intron_1_of_22)    1   1635659 1748291 112633  2   7837    36723
```